# retriving data from a php object inside an array

Tags: php

I have an object contained inside an array

```
array(1) { 
["main"]=> object(Profile)#151 (20) 
{ 
["field_first_name"]=> array(1) { ["und"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["value"]=> string(6) "Fred" ["format"]=> NULL ["safe_value"]=> string(6) "Fred" } } } 
} 

}
```

I am trying to get the value "Fred" from this array.
I thought I could do this

```
$first_name= $profile['main']->['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value'];
```

but it didn't work. It actually gave me an error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried: `$first_name = $profile['main']->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'];`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

field_first_name is a property of $profile['main'] wich is an object.

```
$profile['main']->field_first_name;
```

And the code you added in your example would be like this.

```
$first_name= $profile['main']->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'];
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't the 'field_first_name' need to be in quotes, as it was in the array?

Comment: because it's not an array key, it's an object property. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your error and return the expected value:

```
$first_name = $profile['main']->field_first_name['und'][0]['value'];
```